# Why can't Bytebuddy instrument org.slf4j classes?

Tags: java, slf4j, byte-buddy

I'm trying to instrument org.slf4j.Logger in order to intercept log calls and store them through a java agent. My code is as follows:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                .with(new AgentBuilder.InitializationStrategy.SelfInjection.Eager())
                .type(hasSuperType(nameContains("Logger")))
                .transform(new AgentBuilder.Transformer.ForAdvice()
                        .include(Agent.class.getClassLoader())
                        .advice(named("info"), LogAdvice.class.getName()))
                .installOn(inst);
```

LogAdvice has the following method:

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
    public static void before(@Advice.This Object obj){
        System.out.println(obj);
        System.out.println("===========ENTERED INFO==========");
    }
```

But this method is never entered.
My approach works fine with other classes I've tried, such as java.util.Map's put() method. Any ideas why instrumentation doesn't work in this case?

Comment: My guess would be that it's either because the way that slf4j loggers are usually obtained (in a static initialization) happens before you are able to instrument the classes in question or because the method of obtaining those instances ends up grabbing pristine versions. I would also recommend printing out the classes matched by your `type`, as it might not be matching what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Register an AgentBuilder.Listener to see what classes are instrumented. I suspect that the class you are looking for is loaded before your agent is registered.

If this is the case, you can register a retransformation strategy to retransform these classes.

By the way: I do not see how eager initialization is useful here. I do not see how any initialization of instrumented classes is required for this.